# Help for positioning text and picture?

Tags: positioning

I'm doing LaTex first time in my life and I need to position image and text in the following way:

```
TEXT HERE                                               IMAGE HERE

Lorem ipsum text text juubaa juubaa              ---------PICTURE---------------

Lorem ipsum text text juubaa juubaa              -                             -

Lorem ipsum text text juubaa juubaa              -                             -

Lorem ipsum text text juubaa juubaa              -                             - 

Lorem ipsum text text juubaa juubaa              -------------------------------

AGAIN TEXT HERE

lorem ipsum etc etc
```

How to do this in LaTex? =) Thank you for any advice

Comment: [Welcome!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Check [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Wrapping_text_around_figures) for a little explanation about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is perhaps using the `graphicx` package for image inclusion and then

```
\begin{tabular}{p{3cm}p{3cm}}
some text here
&
\includegraphics{my-picture}
\end{tabular}
```

although there are (of course :-) ) lots more options this should get you started.

([Welcome to tex.sx...](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx))